# Htaccess Removing .php extension to .html make an URL Not found

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

To remove .php extension from URL and replaced with .html
i have wrote:

```
Options -Indexes
Options -Multiviews
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php $1.html [QSA,L]
```

This work fine and i the extension changed, but i get this message:

```
Not Found
The requested URL /**xxxxxx**.html was not found on this server.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To serve `.php` files as `.html` you can use this code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1.html [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.html$ $1.php [L,NC]
```

Comment: one more question , im sorry for that , i want to make /xxxx.html?id=19 to /19, how i can do it , I have write RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ /xxxx.php?id=$1 [L,QSA] and this in second time RewriteRule ^(\w+)/?$ /xxxx.html?id=$1 [L,QSA] , but it doesn't work

Comment: Actual internal URL is `/xxxx.html?id=19` OR `/xxxx.php?id=19`?

Comment: the file name in server is /xxxx.php and when i put the script that u give me in answer , the url become /xxxx.html

Comment: Hmm this will be big change in these rules which would otherwise be useful for someone looking for `.php -> .html` template. I would suggest opening a new question so that I can address it separately from this thread.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26390342/removing-argument-from-url-to-make-a-seo-friendly-url-htaccess

Answer (score 0):

wrong way round? try

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html $1.php [QSA,L]
```