# removing argument from url to make a seo friendly Url htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i have configurate Htacess to remove arguement from URL *
here's my htaccess so far:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# -----  remove .php to .html --------
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1.html [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.html$ $1.php [L,NC]
# -----  END OF remove .php to .html --------
```

Now i want to make this URL

```
/nettoyage-detail-bureaux.html?id=31&desc=some_text
```

to

```
/31/some_text
```

NB : the file name in server is nettoyage-detail-bureaux.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep your rules like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+nettoyage-detail-bureaux\.(?:html|php)\?id=([^\s&]+)&desc=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/(.+)$ nettoyage-detail-bureaux.php?id=$1&desc=$2 [L,NC]

# -----  remove .php to .html --------
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1.html [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)\.html$ $1.php [L,NC]
# -----  END OF remove .php to .html --------
```