# Lampp .htaccess URL rewrite not working

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have php files on my local server.

**First file is: sanjeev-kapoor.php
Second file is: product-sub.php**

What I am trying to achieve through .htaccess file is, when a user hits in URL
`http://mywebsite.com/sanjeev-kapoor.html`
it should process the page `http://mywebsite.com/sanjeev-kapoor.php`

And when user hits this url: 
`http://mywebsite.com/product/sanjeev-kapoor/tea-set.html`

It should process and show this page:
`http://mywebsite.com/product-sub.php??mid=firstQueryParam&series=secondQueryParam [L]`

Here is my htaccess file content:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>  
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on  
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^/sanjeev-kapoor.html /sanjeev-kapoor.php [L]
RewriteRule ^/?product/(.*)/([^/]+).html /product-sub.php?mid=$1&series=$2 [L]
</IfModule>
```

But its not working. It always shows me 404 Not found error.
**The requested URL /site/product/sanjeev-kapoor/tea-set.html was not found on this server.**

I made it sure that `"Override all"` is there and `require all granted` is there in my .httpdconf file. Also, the rewrite module is enabled in my config file.

Please help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Htaccess Removing .php extension to .html make an URL Not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26383967/htaccess-removing-php-extension-to-html-make-an-url-not-found)

Comment: the link you mentioned redirects every html file to php. while I am having issue about passing query string in url along with html to php rewrite

Comment: Yes, you're not using the exact same URLs. But you look at those rules and apply the knowledge to yours.

Comment: Solved it the other way. The link you marked dupicate didnt help me. Thanks

Comment: So post your solution as an answer.